# hide menu if element is not clicked in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a menu '.options' when the document is clicked, but show it when just an icon '.fa-gear' is clicked. I know is('clicked') is invalid, but I can't figure out what else to do.

```
$(document).click(function() {  
    if($('.fa-gear').is(':clicked')) {
        $('.options').show();
    } else {
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});


<div class="options" style="display: none;">
    <span>Option One</span>
</div>

<i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if the event target is `.fa-gear`

```
$(document).click(function(event) {  
    if($(event.target).is('.fa-gear')) {
        $('.options').show();
    } else {
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the event.target :

```
$(document).click(function(event) {  
    if($(event.target).hasClass("fa-gear")) {
        $('.options').show();
    } else {
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the event target for the class.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {  
    if($(event.target).hasClass("fa-gear")) {
        $('.options').show();
    } else {
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});
```

Another way to do this is to just listen for clicks on the fa-gear class and toggle visibility. I would argue this is a better experience for users.

```
$('.fa-gear').click(function() {  
    $('.options').toggle();
});
```

If you still want to hide the menu on document click but toggle on the gear button, you can combine the two.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {  
    if($(event.target).hasClass("fa-gear")) {
        $('.options').toggle();
    } else {
        $('.options').hide();
    }
});
```